# cumsum по определенным значениям

Tags: python, pandas

Подскажите, что-то не соображу)

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2], 'b': [1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)})
temp['sum'] = temp.b.cumsum()
temp
```

Вот код генерит сумму по столбцу 'b' для всех 'a'.
А как посчитать отдельные суммы 'b' по 'a' = 1 и 'a' = 2 (значений много) те нужно получить столбец [1,2,2,3,0,1,1,2]
Пробовал циклом перебирать 'a' не дождался.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё довольно просто:

```
temp['sum'] = temp.groupby("a").cumsum()
temp
```

Вывод:

```
    a   b   sum
0   1   1   1
1   1   1   2
2   1   0   2
3   1   1   3
4   2   0   0
5   2   1   1
6   2   0   1
7   2   1   2
```

Если после группировки останется не один столбец, то нужно будет указать ещё, какой столбец суммировать:

```
temp['sum'] = temp.groupby("a")["b"].cumsum()
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что надо. Первоначально пробовал temp['sum'] = temp.groupby("a").cumsum() валился с ошибкой, второй вариант подошел.

Comment: @medium2000 Поставьте тогда галочку у ответа, что он правильный/полезный. Чтобы ваш вопрос не висел как не отвеченный на сайте